# Making HM-18 modules detect nearby BLE beacons

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, at-command

I am using the HM-18 modules by DSD tech, and I pushed the following code in:

https://github.com/dinosd/BLE_PROXIMITY

The HM-18 slaves are very similar to the HM-10s, so it should work theoretically. I went through all the code and libraries to see if there were any specs I'd need to change but there doesn't seem to be anything specific to the HM-10s in there that I'd need to adjust.

However, this is all my serial monitor outputs:

OK

OK+Set:1

OK+Set:1

OK+RESET

No device

There are a couple of active beacons near the slave, so it should be able to detect them - my phone can detect them no problem. Does anyone know what could be changed so I can read these beacons?

Any tips would be very appreciated!